# Bullet is not working while converting html content to pdf in iTextsharp in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I have tried the below code in C#.Html content has bullets but it is not 
    showing in created PDF file. In the given example , I have added the two types of bullets one is unorderlist & another one is orderlist.
Could you please give me the solution?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DocToPdfConvertor;
using ClosedXML;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Configuration;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace DocToPdfConvertor.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            // get the HTML code of this view
            string htmlToConvert = @"Types of fruits<div><ul><li>Apple</li><li>Mango</li><li>Banana</li></ul><div>Types of Vegetables</div></div><div><ol><li>Onion</li><li>Tomato</li><li>Potato</li></ol></div><div><br></div>";

            string filename = "PDFfile" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy(hh-mm-sstt)") + ".pdf";           
            string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProfileImages"];
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(filePath, filename);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullpath, GetPDF(htmlToConvert));         


            return View();
        }

        public byte[] GetPDF(string pHTML)
        {
            byte[] bPDF = null;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);

            // 1: create object of a itextsharp document class
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4,25, 25, 25, 25);

            FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();           

            // 2: we create a itextsharp pdfwriter that listens to the document and directs a XML-stream to a file
            PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);


            // 3: we create a worker parse the document
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);


            // 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
            doc.Open();
            htmlWorker.StartDocument();

            // 5: parse the html into the document
            htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);

            // 6: close the document and the worker
            htmlWorker.EndDocument();
            htmlWorker.Close();
            doc.Close();

            bPDF = ms.ToArray();

            return bPDF;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't expect an answer if you are still using the deprecated `HTMLWorker` class. We have moved to [iText 7](http://itextpdf.com/itext7) and HTML conversion is done using the [pdfHTML](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) add-on. If you can't upgrade to iText 7, there's iTextSharp 5 and XML Worker, but be aware that all versions prior to 5 are in maintenance mode (meaning bugfixes only). No further development will be done on iText(Sharp) 5, only on iText 7. The `HTMLWorker` class has been out of "maintenance mode" for many years now. Please stop using it!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *"all versions prior to 5 are in maintenance mode (meaning bugfixes only)"* you surely don't mean the 4.x versions, do you?

Comment: @mkl Sorry, I get agitated when I see people putting themselves in trouble by still using `HTMLWorker` and when I get agitated, I make mistakes. iText 5 has gone in maintenance mode. All versions prior to iText 5 have been discontinued a long time ago.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie make it easy for yourself and use the link above next time. :) (Why am I writing this on Stack Overflow? You are sitting 10 meters away from me in the same office, within talking distance :-D )